# checking if something is a prime python?

Tags: python, primes

```
def prime_check(num):
    if num>1:
        if num == 2:
                return True
        for i in range(2, num+1):
            if ((num%i) == 0):
                print(i)
                return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False
prime_check(99)
```

`returns true` (as in is prime) when it should be false when i use value 99. WHY?

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, you're returning true whenever the input is not divisible by the current number in the loop. So, in the first iteration, when `if` condition checks whether 99%2 == 0, if so then return `false` else return `true`. That's why it returns `True` as `99%2 != 0`.

Just change your code a bit, as you are using `for....else`:

```
if (num >1):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if ((num%i) == 0):
            print(i)
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

You can improve the program by decreasing the range of the loop using `range(2,math.floor(math.sqrt(num)))`:

```
for i in range(2,math.floor(math.sqrt(num))):
    //do the same
```

Comment: @NoCompany, if it answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

When 99 enters into the for loop It checks whether `99%2==0`, as it finds `99%2!=0` `else` block is executed, returns `true` and comes out of the loop without doing further iterations. You need to change the code.

To reduce the complexity you can further use sqrt functions. [You can refer to this](https://youtu.be/V42FBiohc6c)

```
def prime(num):
if num==1:
    return False
else:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i==0:
            return False
return True

print(prime(17))
```